# how to maintain theme color for all page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Want to change the color of my website dynamically, but its picking default color when a page gets refresh. Here's the code

```
$("#red").click(function() {
$(".bg-dark").css({"background-color":"#da2639"});
$(".tab-bar").css({"background-color":"#da2639"});
});

$("#green").click(function() {
$(".bg-dark").css({"background-color":"#32b774"});
$(".tab-bar").css({"background-color":"#32b774"});
});

$("#sky").click(function() {
$(".bg-dark").css({"background-color":"#32b0b7"});
$(".tab-bar").css({"background-color":"#32b0b7"});
});
```

Comment: You will need to store the user choice in a cookie or sessionStorage/localStorage, and evaluate if it is set on page load.  If it is, you apply the changes.  You can find existing questions on the site for both approaches.

Comment: Also note that the best way to achieve this would be to put a single class on a single parent element, such as the `body`, and then hook all styling changes to that class in CSS

Answer (score -2):

Nothing in your jQuery is firing to tell the page to change on refresh/load so it will just stay with the set CSS.

If you want it to save after refresh then use local storage

```
localStorage.setItem("color", "XYZ");
```

Then you can just use a switch statement when the page loads. Use:

```
localStorage.getItem("color");
```